# Select property auto size and height

Tags: php, html, select

Is it possible to make the select box adjust size and height automatically as the content added to it, if so how?

My select code is below:

```
<?php
$dir    = getcwd();
$files = scandir($dir);

foreach($files as $file)
{   
    if (strpos($file,'quiz') !== false)
    {
        $fileName = ucfirst(str_replace('.php', '', $file));
        $quizPages[] = array('name'=>$fileName,'file'=>$file);
    } 
}
?>

<select style="width: 300px" name="quizes" size="10">
<?php
foreach($quizPages as $quiz)
{
    echo '<option name="' . $quiz["name"] . '" onClick="window.location = \'' .    $quiz["file"] . '\'" >' . $quiz["name"] . '</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: If you specify a size, then it will always be that size. Remove that property and leave just `<select>` and it will adjust to the maximum length of the elements.

Comment: If what you're trying to do is have the width be *at least* 300px, you could use `min-width: 300px`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify a width it should adjust automatically. As for the size if you want it to show all the options not be a drop down you need to adjust the size to the size of your `$quizPages` array like so:

```
<select name="quizes" size="<?php echo count($quizPages); ?>">
```

If you want it to be a drop down and only show one option at a time remove the size all together and just say:

```
<select name="quizes">
```

Comment: thanks for the help, p.s i am only using width for "design" purposes

Comment: if i want to cap the height of the box at say 300px but i still want the elements to be added, how would i implement this?

Comment: @user3112130 Now I'm lost. What **exactly** do you want it to be? Can you show at least some screenshots, from your desired result?

Comment: i think i confuse myself and you guys also, sorry. But i did it now, <select style="width: 300px; height: 300px" name="quizes" size="<?php echo count($quizPages); ?>">

Answer (score 0):

By automatically it will adjust the width according to the largest text.So you need to do nothing . specify only the name attribute .